# Ошибка кода, не могу исправить. Python. Библиотека selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Я пытаюсь сделать скрипт, который будет делать скриншот веб страницы. Помогите найти решение проблемы.

Вот мой код:

```
        from selenium import webdriver

        DRIVER = 'D:\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER, options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/")
        screenshot = driver.save_screenshot("my_screenshot.png")
        driver.quit()
```

Вылазит следущая ошибка:

D:\pyMap\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\pyMap\main.py

D:\pyMap\main.py:4: SyntaxWarning: invalid escape sequence '\c'

DRIVER = 'D:\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\pyMap\main.py", line 11, in

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER, options=chrome_options)

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Process finished with exit code 1

Пробовал еще так:

```
        from selenium import webdriver
        
        chrome_driver_path = r'D:\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe'

        url = 'https://www.example.com'

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)
        
        driver.get(url)

        screenshot_filename = 'screenshot.png'
        driver.save_screenshot(screenshot_filename)

        driver.quit()
```

Но все равно не работает... вылазит такая ошибка:

D:\pyMap\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:\pyMap\main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\pyMap\main.py", line 12, in

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=options)

```
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Нужно перевести текст ошибки? Потому что если текст ошибки вам понятен, то непонятно, в чем затруднения.

Comment: @Эникейщик я новичок в python. плохо понимаю, что надо сделать... помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Попробуйте без именования параметра: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_path, options=options)`